# Statically Serving React Files To Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm currently working on a React / Express web-application right now. I am proxying my React API requests to my Express server. Also, just to mention, I used npx create-react-app to setup my React project.

I know proxying won't work when in production (when using a real host). To my knowledge, you are supposed to serve the static files within Express. That means I would need to do npm run build then configure it properly server sided.

Are there any downfalls to this or is this how it's usually done in production? Does statically serving the files take away from any functionality whatsoever?

Thanks.

Comment: When you build your react app, you can use Nginx or Apache HTTP server to serve those files. This gives you more flexibility in terms of routing, redirection and forwarding. There are multiple resources for this, [this](https://medium.com/@timmykko/deploying-create-react-app-with-nginx-and-ubuntu-e6fe83c5e9e7) is one of them.

Comment: And serving static files won’t take away the functionality.

Comment: Ah okay! So all of the routing I have implemented client-sided will still work when served as static files, right? I am using Express as my back-end by the way.

Comment: Yes, client side routing will work, just send the requests to the index.html file.